# how to make a VisualBasic2010 web app open a new browser window for a .htm file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

On my web app's home page, when the user clicks the "About" hyperlink control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink in my default.aspx), I need another browser window to open containing an existing about.htm file.

There are other hyperlinks for "Purpose" and "Description" and "How to" and I would like each to open another browser, so that the user can refer to these while performing operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the following code in page_l;oad event,

```
Hyperlink1.Attributes.Add("target","_blank")
```

or

you can directly change the `target` property of a hyperlink control to `_blank`

This will open the the link in new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink have a Target property that needs to be set with _blank value as shown on example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx

Hope this helps...